# VBA Type's in Classes? alternatives to multiple output variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I understand that the `type` structure is the ancestor of the `class` function. However coding a Type structure is quick, simple and easy. Thus I tried the following without success.

Working inside a class in VBa, I tried to return multiple variables from an internal function to another function within the class.  I have tried to do that with a `type` element, however there is an internal conflict within the class function.

I have two questions:
1.) Are `types` not allowed in classes?
2.) What is a `good practice` method for returning multi-variable outputs from a function within a class?

```
Private Type checkResult
    status As Boolean
    errorp As String
End Type

Function CheckPTID(PTid As String) As checkResult
    Dim plen As Boolean ' PT length
    Dim numdash As Boolean ' numbers and dashes
    Dim titles As Boolean ' Tiles correct

    ' initials
    plen = False
    numdash = False
    titles = False

    ' Checks
    If Len(PTid) = 8 Then plen = True
    If InStr(PTid, "-") > -1 Then numdash = True
    If (Left(PTid, 2) = "XP" Or Left(PTid, 2) = "XA") Then titles = True

    ' output
    If (plen = False Or numbdash = False Or titles = False) Then
        CheckPTID.status = False
        If Not plen Then CheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name length incorrect:" & PTid
        If Not numdash Then CheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name format incorrect:" & PTid
        If Not titles Then CheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name titles incorrect:" & PTid
    Else
        CheckPTID.status = True
        CheckPTID.errorp = "N/A"
    End If

End Function
```

Error given in above code is: User-defined type not defined. Thanks

EDIT:

To help with the understanding of the structure. The following is shown :

```
Class
|--Properties
|--Function: CheckPTID
|--Type: checkResult
```

The real question is, how does one use the `type` function directly in a class without creating a new class.

Comment: On which line does the error get thrown?

Comment: use a sub class, just containing public vars, not properties. `public status as Boolean` and `public errorp as string` in a class `checkResult`  You can create Private types

Comment: Thanks @Nathan_Sav, can you create private Types inside a class?

Comment: If you make your function `Private` (and correct the `numbdash` typo) it should work.

Comment: You can return multiple variables passing them as arguments to `Sub` or `Function` byref (wich is default), and modifying them within that `Sub` or `Function`.

Answer (score 1):

> Working inside a class in VBa, I tried to return multiple variables from an internal function to another function within the class.

If I have understood your above comment, then you are trying to use code outside of the local/module level. As per @Nathan_Sav comment above, declare everything publicly. See below.

```
Option Explicit

Public plen As Boolean ' PT length
Public numdash As Boolean ' numbers and dashes
Public titles As Boolean ' Tiles correct

Public Type checkResult
    public status As Boolean
    public errorp As String
End Type


Public Function CheckPTID(PTid As String) As checkResult

'initials
plen = False
numdash = False
titles = False

'Checks
If Len(PTid) = 8 Then plen = True
If InStr(PTid, "-") > -1 Then numdash = True
If (Left(PTid, 2) = "XP" Or Left(PTid, 2) = "XA") Then titles = True

'output
If (plen = False Or numbdash = False Or titles = False) Then
    CheckPTID.status = False
    If Not plen Then CheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name length incorrect:" & PTid
    If Not numdash Then CheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name format incorrect:" & PTid
    If Not titles Then CheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name titles incorrect:" & PTid
Else
    CheckPTID.status = True
    CheckPTID.errorp = "N/A"
End If

End Function
```

Please let me know how this works for you as I have not tested it out! :)

Comment: I think that works outside of a class, but in a class the error is: **Compile error: User-defined type not defined** this happens on the `Public Function CheckPTID(PTid As String) As checkResult` line. That leads me to think that the structure type is not allowed in a class? but rather a class with a class?

Comment: hi any progress with this??

Answer (score 0):

Your narrative says: *"I tried to return multiple variables from an internal function to another function within the class."* . Thus I assume you want to use that `Type` (and `CheckPTID()` method too) inside your class `only`, i.e. you don't want to use that type in any other module.

Then declare `Private` that type and any other function inside your class that returns a variable of that type (like `CheckPTID()` does)

Furthermore you function has to be amended, since you have to:

- initialize a variable of `checkResult` type by declaring it

  ```
  Dim retCheckPTID As checkResult
  ```
- use it throughout your sub to set its properties

  ```
  retCheckPTID.status = False
  If Not plen Then retCheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name length incorrect: " & PTid
  ...
  ```
- and finally set the return value of your function to it

  ```
      CheckPTID = retCheckPTID
  End Function
  ```

here comes the entire code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type checkResult
    status As Boolean
    errorp As String
End Type

Private Function CheckPTID(PTid As String) As checkResult
    Dim plen As Boolean ' PT length
    Dim numdash As Boolean ' numbers and dashes
    Dim titles As Boolean ' Tiles correct
    Dim retCheckPTID As checkResult

    ' initials
    plen = False
    numdash = False
    titles = False

    ' Checks
    If Len(PTid) = 8 Then plen = True
    If InStr(PTid, "-") > -1 Then numdash = True
    If (Left(PTid, 2) = "XP" Or Left(PTid, 2) = "XA") Then titles = True

    ' output
    If (plen = False Or numdash = False Or titles = False) Then
        retCheckPTID.status = False
        If Not plen Then retCheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name length incorrect: " & PTid
        If Not numdash Then retCheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name format incorrect:" & PTid
        If Not titles Then retCheckPTID.errorp = "** Error Name titles incorrect: " & PTid
    Else
        retCheckPTID.status = True
        retCheckPTID.errorp = "N/A"
    End If

    CheckPTID = retCheckPTID
End Function
```

Comment: @CromeX, did you get through it?